# Find a point (a, b) such that minimizes $|x_1 - a| + |y_1 - b| +... + |x_n - a| + | y_n -b|.$

Tags: algorithms

Given $n$ points on a plane find a point (a, b) such that minimizes $|x_1 - a| + |y_1 - b| +... + |x_n - a| + | y_n -b|.$ Is there any  way to do this faster than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: **Hint:** You can handle the $x$s separately from the $y$s. In each dimension it can be done easily in time $O(n\log n)$ once you realize what you're looking for, and in $O(n)$ time if you know [the right trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henning Makholm pointed out, you can handle the x's and y's separately. The optimal value for $x$ is attained at the median of the $x_i$s if $n$ is odd and in the interval between the two median points if $n$ is even.

Finding the median is in $O(n)$ time.